# Using Firebase to Authenticate login page in a React Native Expo App but have to click the button twice for the full function to execute

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

> I am trying to login using firebase but when I click the button my
> function runs till the part signInWithEmailAndPassword, but for the
> entire function to execute and for me to navigate to the next screen I
> have to click again anywhere on the screen which shouldn't be the
> case.
>
> ```
> Objective
> * Being able to click on the button once when the email and password fields are entered and then navigating to the next screen.  
>
>
> I have tried many ways to rewrite my code and the function and even tried the keyboardShouldPersist = "handled" and "always along
> ```
>
> with async and await but nothing has helped so far.

```
export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    const screen = Dimensions.get("screen");
    // console.log(screen);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate('RegistrationScreen')
    }



    const onLoginPress = () => {
        
      setLoading(true)
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((response) => {
                
                const uid = response.user.uid
                const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
                usersRef
                    .doc(uid)
                    .get()
                    .then(firestoreDocument => {
                        
                        if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                            alert("User does not exist anymore.")
                            return;
                        }
                        
                        const user = firestoreDocument.data()
                        console.log(user)
                        setLoading(false)
                        navigation.push('HomeScreen', {user})
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert(error)
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error)
            })
    }

    // async const onLoginPress = () => {
    //         console.log('function has been read')
    //         setLoading(true)
    //     await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    //         .then(() => {
    //             console.log(Response)
    //             console.log('inside the then statement now')
    //             navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    //         })
    //         .catch(error => {
    //             alert(error)
    //         })
    //         setLoading(false)
    // }

    // async function onLoginPress() {
    //     console.log('func has been read')
    //     setLoading(true)
    //     await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( () => {
    //         // const uid = response.user.uid
    //         // const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    //         // usersRef.doc().get().then(firestoreDocument => {
    //         //     if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
    //         //         alert("User does not exist anymore.")
    //         //         return;
    //         //     }
    //             setLoading(false)
    //             navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    //         })
         
    // }


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          {/* <ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/logpic1.png')} style={styles.container}> */}
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView 
                style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps= "always"
                
                > 
                
                {/* <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
                /> */}
              
                <View style={{paddingTop:'108%'}} >
                  <TextInput
                      style={styles.input}
                      placeholder='E-mail'
                      placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                      onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                      value={email}
                      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      

                  />
                  <TextInput
                      style={styles.input}
                      placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                      secureTextEntry
                      placeholder='Password'
                      onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                      value={password}
                      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      
                  />
                  <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.button}
                      onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
                        
                      <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Log In</Text>
                      <ActivityIndicator size='small' animating={loading} color="#BB2CD9" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <View style={styles.footerView}>
                      <Text style={styles.footerText}>Don't have an account? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>Sign up</Text></Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
               
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            {/* </ImageBackground> */}
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Comment: I had a console.log() inside the onLoginPress function right above setLoading(true) which gets executed but the code below the firebase.auth()...... only gets executed when i click the button again or touch anywhere on the screen again. Please help if you can

Comment: Are you using any Remote Debugger in your browser, if so close this debugger and reload app into the simulator and it should work. Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, Thank you! cheers

Comment: I will add all that information to an answer to your question so that the community can refer to it if anyone faces the same issue, please remember to upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could the case that you are using a Remote Debugger in your browser.

If you are the solution is very simple, close this debugger and reload app into the simulator and it should work again.